# Defining axes in matlab

Tags: matlab, function, graph, plot, fft

I'm trying to plot `f[t]`, Fourier series evaluated at `23` for some periodic square-wave with x-axis limits of `[0,T]` and y-axis limits of `[-1 1]`.

I have a figure 1 which is a plot of `f[t]=subs(bn,[n],23)*sin(w0*23*t)` where `bn` is a fourier coefficient evaluated at `23`. The x-axis runs from `0` to `T=0.1` fine. `t=linspace(0:T)`.

The problem is that the y-axis runs from -0.2 to `0.15`. I want it to run from `-1` to `1`.

I've tried `axis([0 T -1 1])` but the plot becomes blank after this and when I enter >> `plot(t,subs(bn,[n],23)*sin(w0*23*t))` I get the original graph

Edit

```
w0=(2*pi)/T
T=0.1
```

Comment: and the value of `w0` is??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this:

```
syms n;
bn = -2.*((-1  + cos(pi.*n))./(pi.*n));
 pretty(bn)

    2 (cos(pi n) - 1) 
  - ----------------- 
          pi n

t = linspace(0,0.1);
plot(t,subs(bn,23).*sin(10*23*t),'cyan','LineWidth',2.0)
ylim([-1 1])
```

And I was able to set the `y-axis` within your range of interest.

I hope this may help.

Comment: I've entered everything exactly the way you have it here and I get 
??? Error using ==> plot
Conversion to double from sym is not possible.

Comment: @pyler: I edited my answer; earlier I forgot to assign the time vector `t`. Now it should do what you require.